# Is it possible to limit the permissions of a user based on his or her actions?

Tags: linux, selinux, access-control

I'm currently working on a research project, that includes the question, if it is possible to implement a Chinese-Wall based information flow control model based on SELinux. One of the core principles of this model is to limit the access to files, based on the actions of a user.

The question I have is pretty simple. Considering the following directory structure:

```
[root_directory]
    [subdirectory_a]
        - file_1
        - file_2
    [subdirectory_b]
        - file_3
    [subdirectory_c]
        - file_4
    ...
```

If a user accesses any of the files in a subdirectory, is it possible to deny access to the files in all of the other subdirectories.

Let me clear this up with an example: If user *A* reads `file_1`, he must never be allowed to access any other file in `root_directory` unless it is in `subdirectory_a`. If a different user *B* reads `file_3` the same restriction applies, but it is for `subdirectory_c`.

To sum it up: The files a user is allowed to access, depends on the file a user initially reads or writes to. Before the initial access no access restrictions apply.

Is it possible to implement this kind of dynamic access restriction policy with SELinux? If it is possible, which path can lead me to a solution i.e. can a custom policy module solve this problem?

I never used SELinux before, but I read some manuals and configuration examples, but none of them deal with applying or changing access rights based on the actions of a user, so I decided to ask this question here.

Comment: Of course it's possible... you could even have user credentials put on hold until IT action. Doing so depends on your knowledge of the system and of programing.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks you for your reply. I 'm glad to hear it's possible. Please tell we roughly how I can implement this, i.e. which parts of SELinux are involved and which steps would be required to implement a policy like the one I described in my question. The sources I read so far did not help me to find a solution.